# Implementing open close principle when interfaces are different

Tags: c#, solid-principles

I have the following use case for a factory safety system. Currently designing the system as console application.
    - A Machine's speed can be increased or decreased using human input - i or d
    - when the speed is increased above 50, there is an alarm raised
    - There is a safety lock in the machine which can be locked or unlocked again by human input - l or u
    - If the speed of the machine is increased by 10 and safety lock is not locked, then there is an alarm raised

I have implemented the system, however, the system is not scallable. Tomorrow if another safety system introduced, then looks like I need to go back to the existing class and modify.

Implementing open close principle looks to be difficult as functionality like speed increase/decrease (ISpeedController) and machine lock/unlock (ISafetyLock) does not share a common interface.

```
public interface ISpeedController
{
    void Increase();
    void Decrease();
}

public interface ISafetyLock
{
    void Lock();
    void UnLock();
}
```

Moreover, there is an event speed change, which fires whenever speed is changed to raise an alarm. That makes things even more complicated.

Can you help me how the system can be designed so that we can seamlessly add new safety measures in future without impacting the current code?

Thanks.

Comment: Will there _be_ any future safety measures? Sounds like a case of YAGNI.

Comment: Thanks for the comment Markus. Definitely there will be safety measures added in future. Even though if I consider nothing will be added in future, the current code looks quite clumsy. for instance - if(userPresses == i)
 Call increased on ISpeedController
else if(userPresses == d)
 Call decrease on ISpeedController
else if(userPresses == l)
 Call lock on ISafetyLock
else if(userPresses == u)
 Call Unlock on ISafetyLock   ...can we implemented the code using open close principle

Comment: YAGNI = https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it

Comment: Considering that when formatted, it is easily readable and understandable, I would prefer "clumsy looking" over anything that is to highly abstracted, thus badly readable and in turn error prone. Especially when - as in your case - we are talking about safety measures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you just need to go with `convention over configuration` approach.

For example, you can define a common interface with registration:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(IHandleKey);
        var classes = typeof(Program).Assembly // you can get them however you want
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(p => handlerType.IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass)
            .Select(t => (IHandleKey)Activator.CreateInstance(t)) // or use IoC to resolve them...
            .ToArray();

        while(true) {
            var key = Console.ReadLine(); // or however you get your input
            var handler = classes.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Key == key);

            if (handler == null) {
                Console.WriteLine("Couldn't find a handler for " + key);
            } else {
                handler.Handle();
            }
        }
    }
}

public interface IHandleKey 
{
    String Key { get; }
    void Handle();  
}

public class Banana : IHandleKey 
{
    public String Key { get { return "u"; } }
    public void Handle() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I did banana work");
    }
}
```

This way if you need to develop a new feature, all you need to add is one class that contains information about valid key and the implementation logic.

Likewise, if you don't want to have the instances ready to handle the command, you can split this and have an attribute describing the key on the type, like so:

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var handlerType = typeof(IHandleKey);
        var classes = typeof(Program).Assembly
            .GetTypes()
            .Where(p => handlerType.IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass && p.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyHandlerAttribute), false).Count() > 0) // note we're checking for attribute here. This can be optimised.
            .ToArray();

        while(true) {
            var key = Console.ReadLine(); // or however you get your input
            var concreteType = classes.FirstOrDefault(x => ((KeyHandlerAttribute)(x.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyHandlerAttribute), false).First())).Key == key);

            if (concreteType == null) {
                Console.WriteLine("Couldn't find a handler for " + key);
            } else {
                var handler = (IHandleKey)Activator.CreateInstance(concreteType); // or use IoC to resolve them...
                handler.Handle();
            }
        }
    }
}

public interface IHandleKey 
{
    void Handle();  
}

[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
public class KeyHandlerAttribute: Attribute 
{
    public String Key { get; set; }
}

[KeyHandler(Key = "u")]
public class Banana : IHandleKey 
{
    public void Handle() 
    {
        Console.WriteLine("I did banana work");
    }
}
```

**Update** Here's the updated program listing using the second variant and implementing shared state and event-based communication.

To be honest, I find this rather trivial, so feel free to ask any questions as i'm not sure what might appear more confusing and what not...

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace Whatever
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            // This part belongs to IoC as a Singleton
            var state = new State();

            // This part belongs to IoC as scoped services
            var handlerType = typeof(IHandleKey);
            var dict = new Dictionary<String, Object>();

            foreach (var type in typeof(Program).Assembly
                .GetTypes()
                .Where(p => handlerType.IsAssignableFrom(p) && p.IsClass))
            {
                var attributes = type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(KeyHandlerAttribute), false);
                if (attributes.Any())
                {
                    var attribute = (KeyHandlerAttribute)attributes.First();
                    var handlr = (IHandleKey)Activator.CreateInstance(type);
                    handlr.RegisterEvent(state);
                    dict.Add(attribute.Key, handlr);
                }
            }

            // Main routine here
            while (true)
            {
                var key = Console.ReadLine(); // or however you get your input
                var handler = dict.ContainsKey(key) ? (IHandleKey)dict[key] : null;

                if (handler == null)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Couldn't find a handler for " + key);
                }
                else
                {
                    handler.Handle();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // This class allows us to share state.
    public class State : ISharedState
    {
        // As required by the question, this is an event.
        public event EventHandler StateChanged;
        public void RaiseStateChange(object sender)
        {
            this.StateChanged.Invoke(sender, new EventArgs());
        }
    }

    // This makes our Handlers unit testable.
    public interface ISharedState
    {
        event EventHandler StateChanged;
        void RaiseStateChange(object sender);
    }

    // Familiar interface -> note how we have a 'register event' method now.
    // We could instead just use a constructor on the HandlerBase. This is really dealer's choice now.
    public interface IHandleKey
    {
        void Handle();
        void RegisterEvent(ISharedState state);
    }

    [AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, AllowMultiple = false)]
    public class KeyHandlerAttribute : Attribute
    {
        public String Key { get; set; }
    }

    // To avoid boilerplate in our handlers for registering/unregistering events we have a base handler class now.
    public abstract class HandlerBase: IHandleKey
    {
        protected ISharedState _state;
        public abstract void Handle();
        public void RegisterEvent(ISharedState state)
        {
            this._state = state;
            this._state.StateChanged += OnStateChanged;
        }

        public abstract void OnStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e);

        ~HandlerBase()
        {
            this._state.StateChanged -= OnStateChanged;
        }
    }

    // Actual handlers...
    [KeyHandler(Key = "u")]
    public class Banana : HandlerBase
    {
        public override void Handle()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I did banana work");
            this._state.RaiseStateChange(this);
        }

        public override void OnStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender != this) // optional, in case we don't want to do this for self-raised changes
            {
                Console.WriteLine("State changed inside Banana handler");
            }
        }
    }

    [KeyHandler(Key = "c")]
    public class Cheese : HandlerBase
    {
        public override void Handle()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("I did cheese work");
            this._state.RaiseStateChange(this);
        }

        public override void OnStateChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (sender != this) // optional, in case we don't want to do this for self-raised changes
            {
                Console.WriteLine("State changed inside cheese handler");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: In my scenario, the implementation of IHandleKey - SpeedController & SafetyLock classes has to raise an event to intimate each other whenever speed is changed or SafetyLock is locked or unlocked. This way this classes will know when to raise an alarm.

Do you have any idea how do we take care of this scenario? 

Thanks for the elaborative answer.

Comment: @App see update - this is now a bit of a longer listing, but it achieves what you asked for. Note: I would have probably not bothered with events and just rolled my own `Task.Run()` but it really depends on your workflow.